# what happens when a compiler encounters a Virtual function?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, virtual, keyword

What happens when a compiler encounters a virtual keyword?

code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    virtual void display(){
        cout << "hello,  in class A display()" << endl;
    }
    virtual void funb(){
        cout << "in class A funb()";
    }
};

class B : public A{
    public:
    void funb(){
        cout << "in funb() of class B" << endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    A *a, c;
    B b;
    a = &b;
    a->funb();
    return 0;
}
```

can it not associate with the function definition of `funb()` by looking at the type of b, during compile time?
what exactly happens? This question might seem silly, but I would like to get it clarified.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the optimiser can do whatever it likes as long as the observable behaviour of the program doesn't change

Comment: I've read that runtime polymorphism is achieved using virtual keyword, but I have a doubt that if it can detect it during compile time the way I had mentioned then it must fall under compile-time polymorphism only, but that's not true. So I wanted to know what exactly happens behind the scene.

Comment: Thank you @Alan Birtles